# Django: Is it appropriate to make queries from the template?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have two models, Book and Chapter:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
class Chapter(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE,  related_name="chapter_set")
    index = models.IntegerField()
```

In my template, I present each book and subsequent chapter indexes:

```
{% for book in books %}
  <h2>{{ book.title }}</h2>
  <br>
  {% for chapter in book.chapter_set.all %}
    <p>{{ chapter.index }}</p>
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

This code works fine. However, I hear repeatedly that it's a bad idea to place logic in the template that could be placed in the view or model. I'm hesitant to implement so many queries from my template if I'm hindering performance.

I'm considering refactoring this code so that the template doesn't process queries through related_name. Is a refactor unnecessary, or am I violating best practices by making queries in the template?

Comment: I don't feel I'm qualified enough to give a thorough answer here, but take a look at prefetch_related(): https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related

Comment: @Ffion , maybe "books" comes from a prefetch related :)

Comment: In my opinion, it is a better idea to massage data on view and send it cooked to view. Paginate, max, count, annotations or just apply filters seems cleaner on view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's a bad practice, for a few reasons:

- Templates are designed to silence any errors when resolving variables. For this reason it's much easier to debug something complex like a query, if it's in the view where an error will be raised and can be dealt with.
- What happens when instead of doing `.all` you suddenly need to do `.filter(attribute=value)`. Now you can no longer do this and you have to move it back to the view. It would be much better just to have the query in the view in the first place. (Yes, there are ways round this example, but there will be situations where there's not. It'll make your life so much easier to have queries in the view to start with).
- Queries in a template reduce the reusability of that template.
- Just from general programming principles. It's good to have separation of concerns. One place should really just do one
  thing. It's simpler that way. And Templates should just be about rendering data. Not fetching data.

Comment: Much appreciated. Is there a good rule of thumb for what 'logic' should be included in the template? It seems easy to overload the for loops and template_tags if one isn't careful. If you're writing logic in the template, does that mean you messed up elsewhere?

Comment: It's not that there should be no logic in the template. You can loop through your data, use if statements, and yes, use template tags for more complex logic. I guess the emphasis in templates should be on presentation of data, rather than processing it. You should think about your context as not needing too much further processing of the actual data itself. These aren't absolute hard and fast rules, more just guidelines.